# Scout and Prepros syntax error

Tags: compilation, sass, prepros

I need Prepros or Scout to compile SASS on Windows 7 / x86. I get syntax error all the time. Regardless of the code. Can you help me?

```
Syntax error: Invalid CSS after "100%": expected expression (e.g. 1px, bold), was ";" on line 2 of for-loop.sass Use --trace for backtrace.
C:\Users\Adam\Desktop\sass\for-loop.sass
```

code1:
    p {
        width: 100%;
    }

code2:
    @for $i from 1 through 3 {
    .item-#{$i} { width: 2em * $i; }
    }

Answer (score 1):

You're using SCSS syntax, but saving the file as .SASS.  The extension used tells the compiler which syntax you are using, it doesn't automatically detect it.